# grab username with regexp

Tags: regex, postgresql

how to grab username wiith RE ?
For example:

```
User: john_smith

User john_smith

User   john_smith
```

I need to grab john_smith
i tried this `[ \t]+(User)?[: \t]*([.]+)`
but can't get it working.
Can anybody help?

Comment: Can you be more precise about what forms the input is allowed to take? (Your RE requires it to begin with one or more spaces-or-tabs, but none of your examples seem to.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try without the leading `[ \t]+`, which means 'at least one'. Or use `[ \t]*` which means 'as much as you want, maybe zero'.

The word 'User' doesn't look optional, so continue with `User[: \t]*`. The dot is a Joker and matches every Character.

Therefore it doesn't make sense to include it into a group. The rest of the group gets meaningless, and it adds nothing to the dot. Therefore a dot in a group means a literal dot. Use just the dot instead: `(.+)`

```
 [ \t]*User[: \t]*(.+)
```

Comment: This works great, except one thing.
If i have `User: john_smith.Some text`
it return `john_smith.Some text`, i only need `john_smith`

Comment: Then you have to define what might terminate the name. The dot seems a reasonable thing, but on the other hand, the underline could too. If usernames are just a-zA-Z0-9 and underline, then `[ \t]*User[: \t]*([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)` solves your task. Maybe a little improved: `[ \t]*User:?[ \t]*([a-zA-Z0-9_]+)`. If only a literal dot can terminate the name, a negative group would do it:  `[ \t]*User:?[ \t]*([^.]+)`.

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
/User:?\s*(\S+)/
```

In postrgres, it would be something like this:

```
substring('User: john_smith' from 'User:?\s*(\S+)')
```

Comment: i need to do it in Postgre sql, like this
SUBSTRING('User: john_smith', 'User:?\s*(\S+)'),

Comment: I added an example that I built using [the postgresql documentation on regexes](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-matching.html).